# Drawing an object through an array

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, object

Having some problems with this for loop to draw multiple numbers of the same object,

```
for (int i = BALL_RED_START; i<BALL_RED_END;i++)
{
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    Redball[i].Draw(); 
}
```

Redball is being called from a separate class,

```
I get error:2228, left of .Draw must have class/struct/union.
```

Redball is defined at the top of Main.cpp

```
Ball Redball;
```

Ball.cpp:

```
include "Ball.h"
include "Vector2f.h"
include "Vector3f.h"
include "Glut/glut.h"
include "GL/gl.h"
include "GL/glu.h"

Ball::Ball(void)
{
    Vector3f Temp_position;
    position = Temp_position;
    Vector3f Temp_velocity;
    velocity = Temp_velocity;
}

Ball::~Ball(void)
{
}

void Ball::SetPos(Vector3f New_position)
{
    position = New_position;
}

void Ball::Draw()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(position.X(), position.Y(), position.Z());
    glColor3d(1, 0, 0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.3, 50, 50);
    glPopMatrix();
}

void Ball::SetVel(Vector3f New_velocity)
{
    velocity = New_velocity;
}

Vector3f Ball::GetPos()
{
    Vector3f temp;
    temp = position;
    return temp;
}
```

Just trying to draw 8 of these balls.

Comment: Didn't you think we'd like to know what the lefthandside of .Draw _is_? How/were is Redball being declared, my friend?

Comment: I've tried -> no luck so far!

Comment: Perhaps drop me a comment on [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667147/drawing-an-object-through-an-array/5667177#5667177) when you have more info, I won't have to check back so often

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you need this

```
Redball[i]->Draw();
```

But there is no way to tell

From the code you gave us

Comment: I'm afraid the update (thx) still leaves out the crucial bit. The header file probably defines operator[](...) for Ball, this is the crucial missing bit :)

Answer (score 2):

That error means that . accessors are for real data.  Structs Classes or uninons in this case you have a pointer to your class not an instance.

Try and see if that works for ya.

```
Redball[i]->Draw()
```